# Python Sklearn Pipeline with array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to create a classifier using Python and Sklearn. I currently have all my data imported successfully. I have been trying to follow a tutorial from [here](http://carrefax.com/articles-blog/2018/2/5/using-scikit-learn-on-your-own-text-data), changing it a bit as I go. Later into the project I realized that their training and testing data was much different then mine. If I understand it right they had something like this:

```
X_train = ['Article or News article here', 'Anther News Article or Article here', ...]
y_train = ['Article Type', 'Article Type', ...]
#Same for the X_test and y_test
```

While I had something like this:

```
X_train = [['Dylan went in the house. Robert left the house', 'Where is Dylan?'], ['Mary ate the apple. Tom ate the cake', 'Who ate the cake?'], ...]
y_train = ['In the house.', 'Tom ate the cake']
#Same for the X_test and y_test
```

When I tried to train the classifier with there pipeline:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
     ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, 
     verbose=1)),])
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

At this line:

```
text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After doing research I now know that is because I am inputting a array for my `X_train` data instead of a string.
So my question is, how do I construct a pipeline that will accept arrays for my `X_train` data and a string for my `y_train` data? Is this possible to do with a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tokenizer` attribute to tell the `CountVectorizer` to each list as a single document and turn the `lowercase` option to `False` like this

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda single_doc: single_doc,stop_words='english',lowercase=False)),
 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
 ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, 
 verbose=1)),])
```